# How to make javascript continue even if element is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectedindex

Here's my problem: the following code stops working if elements above **#sizem** and/or **#sizedivided** is not present. The ecommerce store removes the elements/id when a product doesn't require said elements/id.

It seems to me that the code only works if all elements are present at the same time.
Is there another way to do this and avoid the code stopping?
This is supposed to be aplied to a a dropdown with an alert if the user hasn't selected a size and/or color when attempting to purchase/add to basket

```
$('#prod-buy').click(function(){

  if ($("#color")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Select color");
            return false;
        }

  if ($("#sizem")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Select size");
            return false;
        }         

  if ($("#sizedivided")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert("Select size");
            return false;
        }      
});
```

Comment: What about using a try-catch?

Comment: Are you using the same id on multiple elements? (eg, `color` and `sizem`)

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `id` attribute on more than one HTML element, they are supposed to be used for identifying a single element. If you need to target more than one, use the `class` attribute, and just replace `#` with `.` in your selectors to select by class.

Comment: You can check `if($("#sizem").length) {`

Comment: check `if($("#sizem")){ // your code here}`

Comment: @HiravSampat check the docs - that will always be truthy even if no elements match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be checking whether each element is present.

With jQuery use the length property:

```
if($('#sizem').length) {
    if ($("#sizem")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select size");
        return false;
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to test on whether there's an element. Straight from your code you could do this

```
$('#prod-buy').click(function(){

    if ($("#color")[0] && $("#color")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select color");
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#sizem")[0] && $("#sizem")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select size");
        return false;
    }         

    if ($("#sizedivided")[0] && $("#sizedivided")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Select size");
        return false;
    }
```

});

that way you test wether there's an object before trying to access a property of it (or of undefined). There are other ways to clean it up, but requires more restructuring your code and would thus hide the cuase for you

Comment: This didn't work with my example :(
Solved by @RamblinRose, though.

Thaks for the reply!